# Are self-closing tags mandatory?

Tags: html, resharper

I tried the following HTML in visual studio and I got this error from ReSharper: "Element `link` is a void element and cannot have a closing tag."

```
 <link href="a.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"></link>
```

The webpage still ran with all css intact. However, I'm not sure if manually closing all tags like this, even the ones I've always seen as self-closing such as `<input />`, is valid or if the browser automatically fixed my mistake for me.

Comment: I think it depends on the Doctype your using. What is your doctype?

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html>

Comment: FYI that's the HTML5 doctype

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Are self-closing tags valid in HTML5?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3558119/are-self-closing-tags-valid-in-html5)

Comment: Tl;Dr it's optional but if your being strict you could argue it's invalid on void elements as it's never required.

Comment: @Liam Interesting, so bad coding practices aside, I can close all tags with <tag></tag> and it'll be valid and work?

Comment: According to that dupe question, yes. I'm pretty sure most browsers would be happy with it. Though technically if it is a void element(contains no content) then it should be self closed.

Comment: @Liam Thanks. P.S. It's not a duplicate because the other guy is asking whether closing tags on non void elements are necessary and I'm asking whether self-closing tags on void elements are necessary. Although both questions are on the same topic, the context is different.